# Remove const qualifiers in template C++

Tags: c++, constants

How can I remove all const qualifiers from a data type?

I tried to use `std::remove_cv` but it didnt work.

```
std::remove_cv< const char *>::type
```

Isn't it the same as `std::remove_cv<char*>::type`?

Thanks.

Comment: @DiegoBasch: `std::remove_const` only removes the top-level const.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trait is doing everything correctly:

`const char*` is the same as `char const*` and **neither is the same as `char* const`**. So in your case, it’s the *pointee* that’s `const`, not the pointer. And `remove_const` (somewhat logically) only removes the outer `const`, not inner ones.

If you really want to remove the `const`ness of the pointee, you can do it like this:

```
using T = char const*;
using NoConstT = std::add_pointer<std::remove_cv<std::remove_pointer<T>::type>::type>::type;
```

(Although `std::add_pointer<T>::type` could be dropped in favour of the simpler `T*` …)

That is: remove the pointer, remove the `const` of the pointee, make the result a pointer again.

In fact, this is a good opportunity to use use [R. Martinho Fernandes’](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46642/r-martinho-fernandes) excellent [Wheels](https://bitbucket.org/martinhofernandes/wheels) library which provides convenient shortcuts for such nested traits:

```
#include <wheels/meta.h++>
using namespace wheels;
…

using NoConstT = AddPointer<RemoveCv<RemovePointer<T>>>;
```

Much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a standard way to do this, you will need to write your own:

```
template<typename T> struct remove_const_recursive { typedef T type; };
template<typename T> struct remove_const_recursive<T const volatile> {
    typedef typename remove_const_recursive<T>::type volatile type;
};
template<typename T> struct remove_const_recursive<T volatile> {
    typedef typename remove_const_recursive<T>::type volatile type;
};
template<typename T> struct remove_const_recursive<T const> {
    typedef typename remove_const_recursive<T>::type type;
};
template<typename T> struct remove_const_recursive<T&> {
    typedef typename remove_const_recursive<T>::type& type;
};
template<typename T> struct remove_const_recursive<T*> {
    typedef typename remove_const_recursive<T>::type* type;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it recursively.  Match `T*` in a specialization, then reapply the `*`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the differences between a constant pointer and a pointer pointing to const and the various [`type_traits`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/) with

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_same<std::remove_const<const char*>::type, char*>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_same<std::remove_const<char* const>::type, char*>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_same<std::add_pointer<std::remove_const<std::remove_pointer<const char*>::type>::type>::type, char*>::value << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

which gives as output

> 0
>   1
>   1